# IOS - How can I update the interface of an element while scrolling the element?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView, with a div in it that has overflow that the user can scroll.  The background color of the content inside the div changes based on a timer.

While I am scrolling the content inside the div, the background color won't change until I release my finger.

Is there a way to still allow the interface within the div to update while I'm scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Apple's WebView does not allow you to change the UI during scrolling. Well, you can update it, but it won't redraw until the view finished decelerating.

That probably is the reason why only a single didScroll-event is sent - when decelerating finished.